# How to animate mesh visibility/collection visibility fade in or fade out without using material?

Tags: visibility

I have 50 mesh objects sharing same material. When I fade out visibility using **Transparent BSDF & Mix Shader** node, all object sharing same material fade out. But how can I animate all 50 object fade out one second after another while sharing same material? Do I have to create 50 materials? How to animate fade in/out visibility of entire collection?

Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK the answer is no. Not with one material. But you could use animations nodes e.g. or python to achieve this effect without repeating the same boring step to achieve the goal....with...exceptions: E.g. if they are all in a row on x axis you could use that value...

Comment: Which property of mesh object should I animate using python to fade out visibility?

Comment: I would use material alpha value. AFAIK there is no such property on mesh.